error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`
(I have the same problem, and use the same words. It means that still no solution here).
I am building a solo chain from Substrate node template, Now, I am trying to add pallet-contracts on the runtime. I added the following in the root Cargo.toml file:
# extra deps for setting up pallet-contracts
pallet-contracts = { version = "31.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { version = "29.0.0", default-features = false }

pallet-insecure-randomness-collective-flip = { version = "20.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-assets = { version = "33.0.0", default-features = false }
pallet-utility = { version = "32.0.0", default-features = false }

pallet-authorship = { version = "32.0.0", default-features = false }

in the runtime Cargo.toml
# extra deps for setting up pallet-contracts
pallet-assets = { workspace = true }
pallet-authorship  = { workspace = true }
pallet-contracts = { workspace = true }
pallet-insecure-randomness-collective-flip = { workspace = true }
pallet-utility = { workspace = true }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { workspace = true }

and std
std = [
... 
    "pallet-contracts/std",
    "pallet-insecure-randomness-collective-flip/std",
    "pallet-contracts-primitives/std",
    "pallet-assets/std",
...]

and see the error
 error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)

any suggestions here?
I also tried to use this recommendation Error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`
but no result.

Actually problem here is bigger than I though.
I suppose problem with versions.
Looks like this repo https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk-solochain-template which is the lates version, do not work with any existing examples of pallet_contratcs integration.
And I don't know what to do. Use older version of this template ?
Or maybe someone has successful experience with contracts and this version of repo. Please share your experience.

pallet-contracts = { version = "38.0.0", default-features = false } .
This is compatible version in the template (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk-solochain-template)
Note:

pallet-contracts-primitives was unused  and removed
You can refer how Aleph import with newer pallet-contracts version (https://github.com/aleph-zero-foundation/aleph-node)

